# Узнать значения checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть примерно следующий html код, внутри fieldset находится много чекбоксов, точное количество чекбоксов неизвестно:

```
<fieldset>
<label for="checkbox-6">
    Чекбокс 1
    <input type="checkbox" value="Значение первого чекбокса" id="checkbox-6">
</label>
<label for="checkbox-7">
    Чекбокс 2
    <input type="checkbox" value="Значение второго чекбокса" id="checkbox-7">
</label>
<label for="checkbox-8">
    В общем, чекбоксов очень много...
    <input type="checkbox" value="Значение третьего чекбокса" id="checkbox-8">
</label>
</fieldset>
```

я с помощью jquery добрался до тега fieldset и получил его html:

```
$("body").is("fieldset").html()
```

А дальше не соображу как сделать...

Надо выбрать все **отмеченные** чекбоксы и записать их **значения (value)** в перемнную **a**

Например, отмечены чекбоксы 1 и 2, значит на выходе должна быть одна переменная (a) со значением = "Значение первго чекбоксаЗначение второго чекбокса"

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так :

```js
function fn() {
  let a = '';
  document.querySelectorAll('fieldset input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach(e => a += e.value);
  console.log(a);
};

function fn2() {
  let a = '';
  $('fieldset input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    a += this.value;
  });
  console.log(a);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <label for="checkbox-6">
    Чекбокс 1
    <input type="checkbox" value="Значение первого чекбокса" id="checkbox-6">
</label>
  <label for="checkbox-7">
    Чекбокс 2
    <input type="checkbox" value="Значение второго чекбокса" id="checkbox-7">
</label>
  <label for="checkbox-8">
    В общем, чекбоксов очень много...
    <input type="checkbox" value="Значение третьего чекбокса" id="checkbox-8">
</label>
</fieldset>

<input type="button" value="Go(js)" onclick="fn();" />
<input type="button" value="Go(jquery)" onclick="fn2();" />
```

Comment: Я нашел этот элемент (fieldset) следующим образом: $("body").is("fieldset").html() можно ли как-нибудь от этого отталкиваться?...

Comment: @IllyaIllya [JQuery is](http://api.jquery.com/is/), не знаю, как вы через эту функу находите елемент