# Получить значения checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть следующий html код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer">
        <input type="checkbox" class="answer1" value="Hello">Hello
        <input type="checkbox" class="answer2" value="World">World
        <input type="checkbox" class="answer3" value="!">!
        ...Неизвестное кол-во чекбоксов на странице...
     </div>
     <div>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer">
       <input type="checkbox" value="answer1" value="Hello">Hello
       <input type="checkbox" value="answer2" value="World">World
       ...Неизвестное кол-во чекбоксов на странице...
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Go!" class="submit">
  </body>
 </html>
```

Количество div'ов и количество чекбоксов на странице неизвестно, в каждом диве по одному пустому полю (Your answer)

Написал такой js код:

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    $("div").each(function(i,elem){
        //Записываем значение текстового поля
        var inputvalue = $(elem).find('input[type="text"]').val();
        var checkboxvalue = "???";
        $("body").html($("body").html() + inputvalue + checkboxvalue);
    });
});
```

А вот как дальше не пойму, задача следующая:

Получить значения (value) **ОТМЕЧЕННЫХ** чекбоксов в пределах одного div'a (в одном div неизвестное кол-во чекбоксов), после записать в перемунную checkboxvalue. После, проверяем также и второй div, и делаем с ним те же самые действия

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: Если это ваш код (это кстати невалидный html - чекбоксы должны лежать в `<form>`), то воспользуйтесь приведённым как дубликат вопросом.

Comment: @AK самое "смешное", что у автора уже есть подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873244) с готовым [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873263/191745)

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, чем Вам не подошло [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/873263/191745), предоставленное Вам ранее ?

Comment: @Alex извиняюсь, забыл о том вопросе :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
  var res = '';
    $("div").each(function(i,elem){
        //Записываем значение текстового поля
        var inputvalue = $(elem).find('input[type="text"]').val();
        res = inputvalue + ': ';
        var arr = $(elem).find('input:checkbox:checked');
        $(arr).each(function(i, el) {
          var checkboxvalue = $(el).val();
          res += " " +checkboxvalue;
        });
        console.log(res);
        $("body").html($("body").html() + '<br>' + res);
    });
});
```

Comment: на сайте есть встроенный [fiddle](http://prntscr.com/lffknj)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Тест</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="block-1" data="1" class="cli">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer">
        <input type="checkbox" class="answer1" value="Hello">Hello
        <input type="checkbox" class="answer2" value="World">World
        <input type="checkbox" class="answer3" value="!">!
        ...Неизвестное кол-во чекбоксов на странице...
    </div>
    <div id="block-2" data="2" class="cli">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer">
       <input type="checkbox" value="Hello">Hello
       <input type="checkbox" value="World">World
       ...Неизвестное кол-во чекбоксов на странице...
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.cli').on('click',function(){
                let data = $(this).attr('data');
                let checkboxvalue=[], i, c_m = $('#block-'+data+' input:checkbox:checked');
                for (i = 0; i < c_m.length; i++) {
                    checkboxvalue[i]=$(c_m[i]).val();
                }
                console.log(checkboxvalue);
            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```